# efficient use of inotifywait to detect if no files are created

Tags: bash, logging, inotifywait

I'm doing a script to see if a certain device writes on the disk or not.
I ended up with this:

```
    cd
mkdir -p /var/logfiles

CAMERANAME="tvcc16"
DIR='/share/HDA_DATA/video4/' #tvcc16
ALERTPATH="/var/logfiles/$CAMERANAME.alert"

while true; do

FILE_IS_WRITTEN=0
    echo "$FILE_IS_WRITTEN" > /var/f_is_w

    inotifywait -r -t 30 $DIR -e create | 
    while read path action file; do 
    echo "Written '$file' in '$path' via '$action'." | grep jpg | grep -v "INFO"
    FILE_IS_WRITTEN=1
    echo "$FILE_IS_WRITTEN" > /var/f_is_w
    done 
    FILE_IS_WRITTEN=$(cat /var/f_is_w)
    rm -rf /var/f_is_w

    if [ $FILE_IS_WRITTEN -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "NOREC (Status: $FILE_IS_WRITTEN)"
        echo "recerror: camera is not recording!" > $ALERTPATH
    else
        echo "REC (Status: $FILE_IS_WRITTEN)"
        echo "ok: camera is recording!" > $ALERTPATH
    fi

done
```

The problem is that every time the cycle restart, inotifywait has to set up watches again.
It's resource and time expensive...
Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Not an acute problem here, but you should avoid using uppercase for your private variables -- they are reserved for system use.

Comment: oh that's something i didnt know.

Thanks for pointing that out, i'll keep in mind